# how to plot arrow on two matrix(one is theta, another is length)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two numpy arrays already, one is the theta, another is the length:

```
for example, 
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.int32) #length of the arrow
y = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]], np.float) #theta of the arrow
```

then I want to plot arrow on this 3*2 image (assume this is a 2*3 pixels image),each arrow on each pixel, I expect 6 arrows, but do not know how to plot, many thanks

Comment: Maybe [quiver](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/quiver_simple_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-quiver-simple-demo-py) is suitable?

Comment: how to use quiver? for this? I also tried but failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to use quiver is to calculate u,v coordinates for the arrows using length times cos and sine of the angle.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.int32)  # length of the arrow
y = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]], np.float)  # theta of the arrow
u, v = x * (np.cos(y), np.sin(y))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
q = ax.quiver(u, v)
plt.xlim(-0.5, len(x[0]) - 0.5)
plt.ylim(-0.5, len(x) - 0.5)
plt.xticks(range(len(x[0])))
plt.yticks(range(len(x)))

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]